# Mono called multiple time when not necessary

Tags: spring-boot, project-reactor

I'm trying to convert a normal code in a reactor write flow (i'm quite new with reactor), but I'm having problems and I don't know how to solve it.

```
public String magnetCreation(String name, MultipartFile file) {

    // XLS file save
    var xls = fileStorage.save(file);
    // Excel Parsing
    var data = excelParser.readFile(xls.toAbsolutePath().toString());

    // Delete excel file
    fileStorage.deleteFile(xls);

    // Create one CSV file for each BH curve
    List<MagnetBHCurveURL> urls = new ArrayList<>();

    final MagnetDetails details = new MagnetDetails(name, false, List.of());

    data.bhCurves().forEach(curve -> {

        var csvFile = generateCSV(curve);

        // Now the file name is generated on the fileserver
        var savedName = fileServer.uploadFile(csvFile, uploadPath).block();
        urls.add(new MagnetBHCurveURL(savedName, curve.temp));
    });

    log.info("URL csv upload: {}", urls);

    // thing creation
    var thingJsonObject = magnetUtility.createThing(details, data.summary(), urls);
    var id = twinUtility.create(thingJsonObject);
    // Return thingId
    return id;
}
```

To this

```
public Mono<String> magnetCreation(String name, Mono<FilePart> file) {
var xlsElaborated = fileStorage.save(file).map(path -> excelParser.readFile(path.toAbsolutePath().toString()));

var urls = xlsElaborated.flatMapMany(data -> Flux.fromIterable(data.bhCurves()))
        .flatMap(curve -> {
            var csv = generateCSV(curve);
            return fileServer.uploadFile(csv, uploadPath)
                    .map(url -> new MagnetBHCurveURL(url, curve.temp));
        }).collect(Collectors.toList());

return Mono.zip(xlsElaborated, urls).map(x -> {
    var mData = x.getT1();
    var urlsLists = x.getT2();
    final MagnetDetails details = new MagnetDetails(name, false, List.of());
    return magnetUtility.createThing(details, mData.summary(), urlsLists);
}).flatMap(thingJsonObject -> twinUtility.createAsync(thingJsonObject));
```

Now this code works, but the **excelParser.readFile** is called twice, and I don't understand why.

Comment: I guess it is called twice because you are calling `xlsElaborated` in 2 places `var urls = xlsElaborated.flatMapMany` and in `Mono.zip(xlsElaborated, urls)`.

Comment: Oook, but I thought **xlsElaborated** was already calculated, so I didn't think it would be executed 2 times, should be computed at this row **xlsElaborated.flatMapMany** so here **Mono.zip(xlsElaborated, urls)** should have already been calculated, or not?

Comment: Actually `Publishers by default do not produce any value unless at least 1 observer subscribes to it. Publishers create new data producers for each new subscription.` you can look at this [article](https://www.vinsguru.com/reactor-hot-publisher-vs-cold-publisher/)